# How do I configure Rails to send emails on 500 error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometimes in production, some piece of code with a specific input might break with a 500 error.  How can I configure Rails 3 to automatically send the traceback to an email when there's a 500 error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out [ExceptionNotification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification). That's exactly what it was designed for.

And if you want even better visibility I would suggest you set up an Error Catcher. It's basically the upgraded version of ExceptionNotifier. Airbrake works well but I prefer the open source equivalent Errbit. https://github.com/errbit/errbit

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one [ExceptionLogger](https://github.com/ryancheung/exception_logger) . It allow you log exceptions inside a database table.